# Switching between Scenes in AndEngine Losses control of my physics body

Tags: controller, box2d, andengine, game-physics

I am having a problem with the movement of my player once I return to my Game Scene.

I am able to control my player with controls. I have done it with both On Screen Controls and with On Area Touched sprites, but both fail when I return to my Game Scene. Both controls would still get input, but would no longer move my player.

This is all done in my GameScene that extends BaseScene

Here is how I set up my animated sprite and physics world:

```
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Creates and Registers Physics World
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    this.mPhysicsWorld = new FixedStepPhysicsWorld(30, new Vector2(0, 0), false, 8, 1);
    this.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsWorld);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Creates and Adds the Animated Sprite, Sets Camera Chase Entity
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    player = new AnimatedSprite(18 * 32, 43 * 32, ResourceManager.getInstance().mPlayerTextureRegion, ((DragonsReignActivity)activity).getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    camera.setChaseEntity(player);
    final FixtureDef playerFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0, 0.5f);
    mPlayerBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, player, BodyType.DynamicBody, playerFixtureDef);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Register Physics Connector
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(player, mPlayerBody, true, false)
    {
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //Updates Chase Entity
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            @Override
            public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed)
            {
                    super.onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
                    camera.updateChaseEntity();
            }
    });

    physicsHandler = new PhysicsHandler(player);
    player.registerUpdateHandler(physicsHandler);
    attachChild(player);
    player.setZIndex(10);
```

Here is how I am currently setting up my controls:

```
public void attachControls()
{
    mDigitalOnScreenControl = new DigitalOnScreenControl(0, ((DragonsReignActivity)activity).CAMERA_HEIGHT - ResourceManager.getInstance().DPADBacking.getHeight(), this.camera, ResourceManager.getInstance().DPADBacking, ResourceManager.getInstance().DPADKnob, 0.1f, ((DragonsReignActivity)activity).getVertexBufferObjectManager(), new IOnScreenControlListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onControlChange(BaseOnScreenControl pBaseOnScreenControl,  float pValueX,  float pValueY) 
        {
                if (pValueY == 1){
                        // Up
                        if (playerDirection != PlayerDirection.UP)
                        {
                            player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 0, 2, true);
                            playerDirection = PlayerDirection.UP;
                        }
                }else if (pValueY == -1){
                        // Down
                        if (playerDirection != PlayerDirection.DOWN)
                        {
                            player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 3, 5, true);  
                            playerDirection = PlayerDirection.DOWN;
                        }
                }else if (pValueX == -1)
                {
                        // Left
                        if (playerDirection != PlayerDirection.LEFT)
                        {   
                            player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 6, 8, true);
                            playerDirection = PlayerDirection.LEFT;
                        }
                }else if (pValueX == 1)
                {
                        // Right
                        if (playerDirection != PlayerDirection.RIGHT)
                        {

                            player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 9, 11, true);
                            playerDirection = PlayerDirection.RIGHT;

                        }
                }else{
                    if (player.isAnimationRunning())
                    {   
                        player.stopAnimation();
                        playerDirection = PlayerDirection.NONE;
                    } 
                }

                if(player.getX() >= 576 && player.getX() <= 736 && player.getY() <= 672 && player.getY() >= 576)
                {
                    PLAYER_VELOCITY = 4;
                    Log.e("Collision Box", "You are in the Box. Player Velcocity = " + PLAYER_VELOCITY);

                }
                mPlayerBody.setLinearVelocity(pValueX * PLAYER_VELOCITY, pValueY * PLAYER_VELOCITY);
        }
    });
    this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setAlpha(0.5f);
    this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setScaleCenter(0, 128);
    this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setScale(1.25f);
    this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlKnob().setScale(1.25f);
    this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.refreshControlKnobPosition();
}
```

Lastly this is how I return back to the Game Scene Where all this is at:

```
@Override
public void onBackKeyPressed() 
{
    SceneManager.getInstance().setScene(SceneManager.SceneType.SCENE_GAME);

    camera.setChaseEntity(GameScene.player);

}
```

I know when I return to my scene my controller still get input, but the character will not move.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you have to apply linear velocity to your player body

Comment: @Siddharth I connect my player(my animated sprite) to my mPlayerBody(physics object). So when I move my physics object my player also moves with it. I did this as a work around to TMX collisions that I couldn't get working properly so I added Physics Objects to the Screen on Top of my Collidable TMX Tiles. So the line   mPlayerBody.setLinearVelocity(pValueX * PLAYER_VELOCITY, pValueY * PLAYER_VELOCITY); does move the player around properly until I change Scenes and come back to my Game Scene

Comment: Basic rule of thumb is that if you are using physics world then you can only able to move object with using physics related task only otherwise you can not see any effect on the screen. That happens already with you.

Comment: @Siddharth Thanks for the responses, but moving the object initially isn't the problem. When I start my game scene everything loads properly, and my character moves as intended, but when I change Scene and come back to my game scene I can no longer move the player. The controller still gets input fine, but it will no longer move the player.

Comment: Sorry for last two comments, I didn't seen your velocity statement. If you are using physics world then there is no need of physics handler. Also when you change scene at that time you have to clear your physics related stuff at that time so next time you come all new objects get created.

Comment: @Siddharth Thanks again for the response. That makes since and would work if I created a new game scene every time I come back to it, but all I am doing is changing the scene. If I reset all my physics object I don't know how I would recreate them when I come back to the scene.

Answer (score 0):

- Test whether your body is updating position or not.

  1. If body is updating and sprite is not responding to your inputs then its falt with your sprite.
  2. I am having doubt that why you placed  "registerUpdateHandler" to sprite.Because you are  already updating  your body through world.Then sprite also automatically will update according to body.
  3. If  not it may be  world is not updating.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Rama. 
1. Both the body and sprite update properly, until I come back to my scene.
2. The Sprite is getting the "registerUpdateHandler" because in the block of code above I use a physics connector to link the player and the mPlayerBody.
3. I am pulling more towards that it is a problem with my world, but I don't know how I would begin to fix this problem.

The main issue is every example out there runs their player around in their main game activity, because I have created the game to run from Scenes with one activity. I cannot find a solution to this.

Thanks,
Frost

Comment: Try by changing  Fixed World to  normal Physics world

Comment: Changing to a normal Physics world doesn't change anything. I think the problem is when I switch scenes and return the CreateScene never get re-called so my physics stuff doesn't get updated. Do you know a way around this?